# Calculate difference of two rows based on another columns entries

Tags: pandas, dataframe, row, subtraction

I have data frame like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| zu | 2.5 |
| ab | 1 |
| fi | 0 |
| zu | 2 |
| ab | 0.5 |
| fi | 0 |
| uv | 1 |
| zu | 2 |
| ab | 1 |

I need two calculate the difference between "zu" and "ab" and position it on a new column

| Column A | Column B | diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| zu | 2.5 | 1.5 |
| ab | 1 | 0 |
| fi | 0 | 0 |
| zu | 2 | 1.5 |
| ab | 0.5 | 0 |
| fi | 0 | 0 |
| uv | 1 | 0 |
| zu | 2 | 1 |
| ab | 1 | 0 |

I tried the diff() and shift() Funktion but that didn't work. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example Code**

```
data = {'Column A': {0: 'zu', 1: 'ab', 2: 'fi', 3: 'zu', 4: 'ab', 5: 'fi', 6: 'uv', 7: 'zu', 8: 'ab'},
        'Column B': {0: 2.5, 1: 1.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 0.5, 5: 0.0, 6: 1.0, 7: 2.0, 8: 1.0}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

**Code**

```
s = df['Column B'].diff(-1).where(df['Column A'].eq('zu'), 0)
```

`s`

```
0    1.5
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    1.5
4    0.0
5    0.0
6    0.0
7    1.0
8    0.0
```

make `s` to diff column

```
df.assign(diff=s)
```

`output`

```
 Column A   Column B    diff
0   zu      2.5         1.5
1   ab      1.0         0.0
2   fi      0.0         0.0
3   zu      2.0         1.5
4   ab      0.5         0.0
5   fi      0.0         0.0
6   uv      1.0         0.0
7   zu      2.0         1.0
8   ab      1.0         0.0
```